# What is the size of the set of spent key images in Monero?

Tags: monerod, monero-research-lab, key-image, txo-set, research

For research purposes, I want to know the following:

1. What is the exact size of the set of already spent key images and how it can be checked? Do we need to download the Monero blockchain to get the size?
2. Using the `is_key_image_spent` api, we can check if a key image is a member of the set of already spent key images or not. Can this set be made a *zero-knowledge* set using some accumulator so that a zero-knowledge set membership or non-membership proof can be given for a particular group element (key image) bypassing this api? Does there exist any accumulator suitable for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 3):

1. Each transaction input has a key image, and there are around 2.1 inputs per transaction on average. So, the 'key image set' is around 2x the number of transactions on-chain.
2. I do not believe a zero-knowledge proof is currently available, although you may find the description of a hypothetical 'unspent proof' in [section 8.1.5](https://web.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf) of Zero to Monero 2 is in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @koe. What is the total number of transactions on-chain so far? Also, is there any difficulty to implement UnspentProve, particularly in ReserveProof?

Comment: I think it's on the order of 10-20mill. Hopefully UnspentProofs can be implemented in Monero at some point, although when that would happen is hard to say. They aren't incredibly difficult to implement, but not super easy either.

Comment: I see 41103595 outputs (output_txs), 35830737 spent keys (spent_keys) and 10325681 txs (tx_indices) in the database right this moment.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the exact size of the set of already spent key images and how it can be checked? Do we need to download the Monero blockchain to get the size?

Yes, you'd need to download the blockchain. Once you have synced the blockchain, you can obtain the count of spent key images by inspecting the database like:

```
mdb_stat -s spent_keys ~/.bitmonero/lmdb/
...
Entries: 35830820
```

> Using the `is_key_image_spent` api, we can check if a key image is a member of the set of already spent key images or not. Can this set be made a zero-knowledge set...

Key images *already* provide a form of zero-knowledge proof - proof that there is no double-spend without divulging which output is being spent. Each ring of outputs (so tx inputs) has a key image which is unique to one of the outputs in the ring but crucially doesn't divulge *which* is the actual output being spent.

Comment: I agree that the key images provide a form of zkp. But for reserve proof, the prover needs to reveal key images for unspent outputs. This is detrimental to the privacy for future transaction. This makes proving a one-time address unspent without revealing the key image important. UnspentProof as suggested by @Koe is a solution to this problem. I was initially wondering about existence of any zero-knowledge accumulator using which we could show that a key image has not appeared without revealing it. I am still curious to know about any such accumulator which could be used for this purpose.

Comment: I have never heard about an accumulator for key images, and I'm not even sure what that would look like.